# Creating a triangle using a ragged 2D array

Tags: python, python-2.7

i need to use a ragged 2D array to create a triangle like the one shown,
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 2
3 3 3
4 4
5

```
def triangle(n):  
    for i in range(n):  
        tri = n  
        for j in range(n-i):  
            tri = tri * 10 - n  
        print tri
```

i have tried this but it returns,
444445
44445
4445
445
45

Comment: Try google, or direct search here for ANY language loops create triangle. We arnt here to solve your homework, so try reading your textbook too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you made atleast some effort, here it is one way to do it

We only need to iterate over the loop once. Since the `index` are `int`, we need to convert to `str`. Also, they start at `0` so either you iterate from `n+1` or use `i+1` to print so you get your expected output. You can then multiply how many times you want to print the numbers which is converted to string.

```
def triangle(n):  
    for i in range(n):  
        print (str(i+1) + " ") * (n - i)
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/VyymXa)